# Assign large numbers of activities at once - Wordpress

Tags: activities

Is there any way of doing this from the interface. I have lots of activities that need to be assigned to a small group of individuals. I want to assign these (currently unassigned ) activities to the corresponding contact. Can't do it through batch update or import, the assigned field isn't exposed.

Comment: worth stating what CMS you are using to help get/avoid answers like mine ;-)

Comment: Couldn't you use the api (through ui (/civicrm/api))?

Answer (score 2):

If there is a way, we didn't find it, and that was partly why Fuzion put a bunch of time in to making it possible to assign/unassign/reassign Activities in Drupal using CiviCRM Entity Actions which is now a submodule of [CiviCRM Entities](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity), Views and Views Bulk Operations, in order to deliver a Calling Tool that could be driven from the Drupal front end. (Is there some way I can mark these types of answer as Drupal-only info?)

Comment: That would work, but as you said, I should have stated the CMS, which is unfortunately Wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention import you could try using the [csvimporter Extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.csvimport), which does include many other Entities such as Activities and provides fields for eg 'assignee' when doing so.